# Is it possible to create popups in pygame that can be deleted/messed around with without effecting what is displaying on the main screen

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

Basically what I want is when you mouse over a unit or item in my game for it to display some basic stats about the item/unit (ideally where the mouse is) like if you hover over the start button on windows it displays a little box that says start.

Is there anyway to do this in pygame so that when I hover over the unit it can display this data on a new surface or level of the screen so that when I stop hovering over I can simply delete/do away with the box of stats and restore what was behind this popup previously ie the background/level/current battle

I would just blit a box at the mouse position and put the stats in that but then I am unsure how I would get rid of this as I have many previous blits behind it and would require me to re draw the entire screen every time I hover off and on a unit which unfortunately is not feasible

Many thanks

Comment: How are you drawing everything to the window?  What is the main-update loop like?  A lot of PyGame programs re-paint the entire window every frame, is your application doing this?

Comment: I just blit images to the screen and use the draw tool when needed. It is not repainting every frame only repainting certain areas when changes are needed or player action has taken place alot of these are done and stored in separate functions such as the battle field, the combat log, the inventory etc so encompassing the hover over into all these isnt viable unfortunately, I probably should have implemented that in the begining but I am far to far along now, you can see a slightly behind in progress version here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fqmuzuf9hliwb1u/AAAhFdT_xx0n0F_TJQUpAXzCa?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, because you are not updating the screen every frame, it's necessary to save the bitmap of what will be "underneath" the pop-up, then use this to erase it later.

Python does *not have* a `Surface.copy_area()`, but it's reasonably uncomplicated to make a Surface the size of the required area to copy, then use the third parameter to `Surface.blit()` - which is the area of the source surface to copy:

```
def copyArea( screen, x, y, width, height ):
    """ Copy a region of the given Surface, returning a new Surface """
    # create surface to save the background into
    copy_to = pygame.Surface( ( width, height ) )                      
    # copy the background
    copy_to.blit( screen, ( 0, 0 ), ( x, y, width, height ) )
    return copy_to
```

The complicated part is rendering the textual elements into a pop-up box!

I don't want to go into detail, but basically you convert each line of text into a bitmap using the given font.  Each of these has its own height and width.  The code needs to sum the heights and find the maximum width to know the size of the target pop-up box.  These can then be drawn in-turn to the target bitmap, applying a margin and line-spacing for each.

Then there's the hovering.  The code needs to first detect the hover.  This is fairly easy, it's just whether the mouse-cursor is within a rectangle.  When it enters draw the popup, when it leaves un-draw it again.

[image: example video]

Reference Code:

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH    = 500
WINDOW_HEIGHT   = 500
WINDOW_SURFACE  = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE

RED       = ( 200,   0,   0 )

class ErasablePopup:
    FOREGROUND_COLOUR = (  86,  54,   8 )  # dark chocolate brown
    BACKGROUND_COLOUR = ( 255, 228, 157 )  # sepia yellowish white
    SIDE_MARGIN       = 7                  # size of corners and margin
    LINE_SPACING      = 1                  # pixels between lines

    def __init__( self, font, message ):
        # First render the text to an image, line by line
        self.image = self._textToBitmap( font, message )
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.under = None                                                                # The underneath image when drawn

    def drawAt( self, screen, position ):
        """ Draw the popup at the given location, saving the underneath """
        x, y = position
        self.rect.topleft = ( x, y )
        self.under = pygame.Surface( ( self.rect.width, self.rect.height ) )              # create surface to save
        self.under.blit( screen, ( 0, 0 ), ( x, y, self.rect.width, self.rect.height ) )  # copy the background
        screen.blit( self.image, self.rect )                                              # draw the rendered-text

    def isShown( self ):
        """ Is this popup drawn to the screen? """
        return ( self.under != None )                                                     # if we're on-screen there's an under

    def unDraw( self, screen ):
        """ Erase the pop-up by re-drawing the previous background """
        # Only erase if we're drawn
        if ( self.under != None ):
            screen.blit( self.under, self.rect )                                          # restore the background
            self.under = None                                                             # release the RAM

    def _textToBitmap( self, font, message ):
        """ Given a (possibly) multiline text message
            convert it into a bitmap represenation with the
            given font """

        height_tally  = 2 * self.SIDE_MARGIN     # height-sum of message lines
        maximum_width = 0                        # maximum message width
        message_lines = []                       # the text-rendered image
        message_rects = []                       # where it's painted to
        # cleanup messages, remove blank lines, et.al
        for line in message.split( '\n' ):    # for each line
            if ( len( line ) == 0 ):
                line = ' '   # make empty lines non-empty
            # Make each line into a bitmap
            message_line = font.render( line, True, self.FOREGROUND_COLOUR, self.BACKGROUND_COLOUR )
            message_lines.append( message_line )
            # do the statistics to determine the bounding-box
            maximum_width = max( maximum_width, message_line.get_width() )
            height_tally  += self.LINE_SPACING + message_line.get_height() 
            # remember where to draw it later
            position_rect = message_line.get_rect()
            if ( len( message_rects ) == 0 ):
                position_rect.move_ip( self.SIDE_MARGIN, self.SIDE_MARGIN )
            else:
                y_cursor = message_rects[-1].bottom + self.LINE_SPACING + 1
                position_rect.move_ip( self.SIDE_MARGIN, y_cursor )
            message_rects.append( position_rect )
        # Render the underlying text-box
        maximum_width += 2 * self.SIDE_MARGIN                                       # add the margin
        image = pygame.Surface( ( maximum_width, height_tally ), pygame.SRCALPHA )  # transparent bitmap
        image.fill( self.BACKGROUND_COLOUR )
        # draw the lines of text
        for i in range( len ( message_lines ) ):
            image.blit( message_lines[i], message_rects[i] )
        return image





### initialisation
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), WINDOW_SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("text player")

### Message Text For Displaying
popup_font = pygame.font.Font( None, 18  )
popups     = []                               # list of popup objects
hover_rects= []                               # list of hover locations

popups.append( ErasablePopup( popup_font, "The Owl and the Pussy-Cat went to sea\n   In a beautiful pea-green boat:\nThey took some honey,\n   and plenty of money\nWrapped up in a five-pound note." ) )
popups.append( ErasablePopup( popup_font, "I smell a Wumpus!" ) )
hover_rects.append( pygame.Rect( 150, 150, 70, 70 ) )  # hot-spot1
hover_rects.append( pygame.Rect( 300, 300, 70, 70 ) )  # hot-spot2

### Background image
grassy_background = pygame.image.load( "big_grass_texture.jpg" )  # ref: https://jooinn.com/images/grass-texture-10.jpg
grassy_background = pygame.transform.smoothscale( grassy_background, ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ) )

### Main Loop
do_once = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Paint the background, but just once
    if ( do_once ):
        do_once = False
        window.blit( grassy_background, ( 0, 0 ) )
        for i in range( len ( hover_rects ) ):
            pygame.draw.rect( window, RED, hover_rects[i], 2 )

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True

    # Do the hover and popup
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    for i in range( len ( hover_rects ) ):
        if ( hover_rects[i].collidepoint( mouse_pos ) ):  # mouse inside the rect?
            if ( not popups[i].isShown() ):
                popups[i].drawAt( window, mouse_pos )
        else:
            # not inside the rect
            if ( popups[i].isShown() ):
                popups[i].unDraw( window )

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Are you god?
Jokes aside thank you so much this was just what im looking for!

Comment: @DataMan - No, I just like to write programs.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this myself, but cannot see why `copy()` it would not work with the display surface as it would with any other screen.

Try just making a copy of the display surface using the Surface `copy()` method (docs [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.copy)) before you put up the popup, and then when you want to repaint the area under the popup you can just blit back the section you need from the copy back into the right place. This assumes that nothing has changed in the area you want to repaint of course, but that would be an issue anyway (and could be handled by blit'ing the changes to the copy if there is one).

You can use the [`area`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) argument of `blit()` to limit the amount you copy redraw from the copy to the display.